# How can I loop through columns in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop through each column of first row and if found Job in column heading then I need to loop through each cell of that column and color entire row if cell value is less than 5. This is what I am trying but failed:

```
Sub rr()
Dim a, i, col As Integer
Dim r As Range

r = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
a = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a Step 1
For col = 1 To r Step 1

If Cells(1, col).Value = "job" Then Cells(1 + 1, col).Activate
For Each cell In r

    If r.Value <= 5 Then ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, r)).Interior.ColorIndex = 38 Else: Selection.Offset(1, 0).Selection

Next c

Next col

Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use conditional formatting, but if it has to be VBA, perhaps something like this?

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim rngColor As Range
    Dim strFirst As String

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Set rngFound = Rows(1).Find("Job", Cells(1, Columns.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone
        With Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns(rngFound.Column))
            .AutoFilter 1, "<=5"
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rngColor = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rngColor Is Nothing Then rngColor.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 38
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "No column with heading ""Job"" exists in this worksheet.", , "Exiting macro"
    End If

    Set rngFound = Nothing
    Set rngColor = Nothing

End Sub
```